# Return type of property in C# .net

Tags: c#, .net

If there is only a set part in a Property, then is there any need to declare a return type?
For example:

```
public string Email
{
   set { email = value; }
}
```

In the above example is there any need of the word "string" after public?

Comment: It's not considered a very good design choice to have setters without getters. (or to have any setter with more public access than the getter.) Consider using a SetEmail() method instead.

Comment: Thanks Mark H. Your advice will really help me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is: It's not possible to have a property without a type

Think that `value` is of the type that you specified so it's not that it's not being used.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The compiler needs to know so that it can check the type when you try to set the property.

Answer (score 3):

Otherwise you wouldn't know the type of `value`.